# When error handling is triggered, the application crashes

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route.

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    ...
    await timeIntervalCheck(req, res);
    ...
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Product added'
    });
}):
```

In it, I call the function `timeIntervalCheck`

Here is the function itself:

```
function timeIntervalCheck(req, res) {
    let end_date = req.body.end_date;
    let starting_date = req.body.starting_date;
    let date = moment(end_date).diff(moment(starting_date), 'hours');
    if (date < 2 || date > 168) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            err: 'The product cannot be published for less than 2 hours and longer than 7 days'
        });
    }
}
```

If the time of the product fits into the period everything works well, but as soon as the periud is less or more then an error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I understand him for what it is, because the headings are already sent when the periud is more or less and I continue to try to send them again. How can I make sure that there is no such error? How to send an error that periud more and not to issue that the product is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should check the result from `timeIntervalCheck` and send the proper response. (or you can check `res.headersent` and stop sending the response twice, but i don't prefer this method)

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  ...
  let checkResult = timeIntervalCheck(req); // please note that only async function requires await flag
  ...
  if (checkResult === true) {
    return res.status(200).json({
     message: 'Product added'
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(422).json({
      err: 'The product cannot be published for less than 2 hours and longer than 7 days'
    });
  }
}):
```

--

```
function timeIntervalCheck(req, res) {
  let end_date = req.body.end_date;
  let starting_date = req.body.starting_date;
  let date = moment(end_date).diff(moment(starting_date), 'hours');
  if (date < 2 || date > 168) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

}